# Error with application.py index in pset7

Tags: python, indexing, sqlalchemy

I get this error when I buy a stock or when I try to go to my index.html:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset7/finance/helpers.py", line 31, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset7/finance/application.py", line 55, in index
    price= stock["price"], total= usd(stocks_total), symbol = symbol, id = session["user_id"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 112, in execute
    statement = statement.bindparams(sqlalchemy.bindparam(key, value=value, type_=UserDefinedType()))
  File "<string>", line 2, in bindparams

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 45, in _generative
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1470, in bindparams
    "bound parameter named %r" % bind.key)
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'price'
```

I think the problem is within  the index function but I really cant find it.  Any help please....

```
def index():

row_symbols = db.execute("SELECT symbol, shares, price FROM portfolio WHERE 
                         user_id = :id", id = session["user_id"])
total_cash = 0

if not row_symbols:
    stocks = []
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:id", 
                      id=session["user_id"])
    return render_template("index.html", stocks = stocks, cash = usd(cash[0]
                           ["cash"]), total= usd(cash[0]["cash"]))
else:

    for row_symbol in row_symbols:
        symbol = row_symbol["symbol"]
        shares = row_symbol["shares"]
        stock = lookup(symbol)
        stocks_total = stock["price"] * shares
        total_cash = total_cash + stocks_total

        db.execute("UPDATE portfolio SET price =: price, total =:total WHERE 
                    symbol =: symbol AND user_id =: id",\
                    price= stock["price"], total= usd(stocks_total), symbol 
                    = symbol, id = session["user_id"])

    update_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:id", 
                             id=session["user_id"] )

    total_cash = total_cash + update_cash

    update_portfolio = db.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE user_id =: 
                                   id", id= session["user_id"])

    return render_template("index.html", stocks = update_portfolio, cash = 
                            usd(update_cash[0]["cash"]), total = 
                            usd(total_cash) )
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace in your question? That would go a long way toward diagnosing your issue.

Comment: This is the traceback https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5c68f6a801a97580ff0f220c9845f0d

Comment: You have a space between the colon and the parameter name: `: price` (and for `symbol` and `id` as well).